# Is it possible to crop an image into complex shapes?

Tags: html, css

I am rather new to CSS, and I was wondering if it is possible to crop an image to make dynamic shapes on my website. Instead of just having a rectangle or square for the photo, I want to be able to cut into it diagonally that matches the color of the sidebar, along with angled text right under. Is it possible for me to dynamically crop the image like this? Or would I have to make use of shapes and overlay them over the image?

[An example of a mockup I made, I would like to be able to either crop the image to be slanted like this or overlay a shape to make it look more dynamic.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipQx4.jpg)

Comment: `clip-path` proberly will be the esiest solution for you. Alternativly `transform/translate` or `pseudo-elements` will work for you aswell.

Answer (score 3):

As @tacoshy mentioned you can use `clip-path` for creating in place image clipping, a pretty cool tool that can help you with creating complex clipping paths is https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

**Example**:

```css
.image-shape {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<img class="image-shape" src="https://image.uniqlo.com/UQ/ST3/eu/imagesother/2020/ut/gaming/pc-ut-hero-mario-35.jpg" alt="Mario" />
```

More info about the `clip-path` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path